# Square is not a monotone function on the set of PSD matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $X,Y$ be real symmetric matrices. We say $X \geq Y$ if $X-Y$ is PSD.

**Question:** What is a basic ($2\times 2$) example of matrices $X,Y$ s.t.:
$$
X \leq Y
$$
but:
$$
X^2 > Y^2
$$
e.g.$X^2 - Y^2$ is strictly positive definite? All I know is that $X,Y$ cannot commute but I am having difficulty coming up with concrete examples.

Comment: take $Y$   p.s.d. but take $-X$  p.s.d.  with large entries. You could just take $X = -2Y.$   With that in mind, actually $X,Y$ are allowed to commute

Comment: not sure about your title question, when both are p.s.d.

Comment: No such example exists. The best you can do is find examples where both $X \leq Y$ and $X \geq Y$ fail to hold

Comment: Note that $X \leq Y$ implies that the $i$th eigenvalue of $X$ is less than or equal to the $i$th eigenvalue of $Y$

Comment: At least, no example exists in which both $X$ and $Y$ are PSD

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example if we allow arbitrary symmetric matrices: take $X = -2I$ and $Y = I$, where $I$ denotes the identity matrix. Of course, we have $X^2 = 4I \geq I = Y^2$.

No example exists in which $0 \leq X \leq Y$ but $X^2 \geq Y^2$. One way to see that this is the case is to note that $X \leq Y$ implies that $\lambda_i(X) \leq \lambda_i(Y)$ (where $\lambda_i(X)$ denotes the $i$th eigenvalue of $X$ in increasing order), and $X < Y$ implies $\lambda_i(X) < \lambda_i(Y)$. So, $X \leq Y$ implies that $\lambda_1(X) \leq \lambda_1(Y)$, which means that
$$
\lambda_1(X^2) = \lambda_1(X)^2  \leq \lambda_1(Y)^2 = \lambda_1(Y^2).
$$
However, $X^2 > Y^2$ necessitates that $\lambda_1(X^2) > \lambda_1(Y^2)$, which is contradicted in the above inequality.